# PHP GD Library Disabling Antialiasing

Tags: php, gd

I'm using a composer package (`dinesh/barcode`) to generate barcode images, but I found out that antialiasing is messing up with barcodes of width 1px.  Essentially turning barcodes of 1-2px into questionable reads.

I've tried drawing the barcode lines with `imagefilledrectangle`, `imagesetthickness` and `imageline`.  These seem to antialias the vertical lines.

Is there a way to bypass the antialiasing of vertical lines?  Or do I need to recompile PHP with GD support to get the `imageantialias(image, boolean)` method?

**Updates:**

I'm using PHP version 5.5.9, and GD version 2.1.1-dev.

When attempting to call `imageantialias($image, FALSE)` I receive a `Call to undefined function imageantialias()` exception.

I have attempted to use these instructions to get the gd-bundled file, but it does not exist for php 5.5.9. (http://nossie.addicts.nl/php5-gd.html)

Comment: Don't you already have the GD library installed? Can't you use the `imageantialias` function?

Comment: It gives me a `Call to undefined function imageantialias()` which is why I'm having issues.  I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: I think I'm just going to not use the image libraries, they seem to be unable to draw single pixel width lines.  I'll just use the SVG functionality.  That said, I'd still like to figure out how to draw un antialiased lines with GD or Imagick libraries.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant but in cairo (another 2d image library) drawing lines at offset 0.5 makes a great difference (e.g. a line `(0,0)--(0,10)` becomes `(0.5,0.5)--(0.5,10.5)`, assuming scale 1:1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I decided to use is three-fold.

1. Generate HTML divs for black and white bars, this sometimes causes issues with printing that I will have to fix to display them during print.  Shouldn't be too hard.
2. Generate SVG images, which seems to be the simplest option, but I don't really know its limitations.
3. Generate barcodes as PNG, but with much wider bars (using 30px for each bit) and then scale down using CSS.  The barcode is close enough that it scans just fine.